# Add a todo list item in SPE (Stani's Python Editor)

Tags: python, ide, todo

How do I add a todo list item in Stani's Python Editor? I think it's something you type in together with the code and it automatically shows up the the todo list panel. However, I do not know the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
#TODO: Something
```

(I didn't try it myself)

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) I experimented with it and found out that adding ! anywhere on the `#TODO` line gives it a priority rank, and shades the item a yellow background (as seen in the Todo panel)
  
`#TODO: I might add this feature` <-- 0 priority
`#TODO: Annoying bug !` <-- 1 priority
`#TODO: Totally annoying bug !!!! Gotta fix this` <-- 4 priority

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old post, but I thought I'd share the following.

Any line starting "#TODO: " will add text to the to-do list/tab (the keyword is case insensitive). You can add one or more exclamation marks - these act as a priority ordering mechanism, the number appearing in the "!" column. Further, the entry (or entries) that have the largest exclamation count are highlighted with a yellow background.

When I discovered how to use this feature, I consigned all my scrappy notes of 'things to fix' to the bin and kept them all 'online' so to speak. It is a very useful feature.